# How to get textarea value using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and using nextjs, Right now i am trying to get value
of "textarea" and "dropdown/select", but i am getting empty result,How can i do this ?
I tried with following code

```
  const msgChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setState({
      ...state,
      [e.target.msg]: value
    });
  };

  const countryChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setState({
      ...state,
      [e.target.country]: value
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        var msg = state.msg;
        alert('msg is '+msg);
        
    }


<form className='row' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
<select className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" onChange={countryChange} name="country">
<option selected>Country</option>
<option value="abc">abc</option>
<option value="xyz">xyz</option>
</select>
                  
<textarea  onChange={msgChange} name="msgs"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="send" className='sendbtn' /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Think it should be `[e.target.name]` not `]e.target.msg]` in all places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the wrong attributes in the `onChange` handlers for both the `textArea` and `select` dropdown.
Assuming you have the below kind of `useState` in your code.

> ```
> const [state, setState] = useState({});
> ```

You should use the below attributes to add your value to the state.

> ```
> const msgChange = (e) => {
>     const value = e.target.value;
>     setState({
>       ...state,
>       [e.target.name]: value
>     });
> };
>
> const countryChange = (e) => {
>     const value = e.target.value;
>     setState({
>       ...state,
>       [e.target.name]: value
>     });
> };
> ```

Access the value below from the state

> ```
> const handleSubmit = (e) => {
>    const msg = state.msgs;
>    const country = state.country;
>    console.log("message ---->", msg, "country --->", country);    
> };
> ```

Comment: unable to get country name , getting "undefined"

Comment: The initial value will be undefined for state.country according to your HTML/jsx structure. When the user selects any new value like "abc", it will be abc.

Comment: Khadelwal in dropdown if i not changed any country(be default) not getting current country(by default country is india) , How can i solve this

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the key to `e.target.msg` which doesn't exist. I assume you meant to set it using the element's `name` instead. You would also need to do that with the select element. So, with that in mind, you can actually combine those two functions into one that handles the change events for both elements.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ state, setState ] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (e) => {
  
    // Destructure the name and value from
    // the changed element
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setState({ ...state, [name]: value });
  };

  // Log the change in state
  useEffect(() => console.log(state), [state]);

  return (
    <form className='row'>
      <select
        className="form-select"
        aria-label="Default select example"
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="country"
      >
        <option selected disabled>Country</option>
        <option value="abc">abc</option>
        <option value="xyz">xyz</option>
      </select>
      <textarea
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="msg"
      ></textarea>
    </form>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```